# OnClickListener in ListView updates a different item on the list

Tags: android-fragments

I have a `ListView` in my `Fragment` class. This `ListView` has three items, and every item in the `ListView` has two buttons, btn+ and btn-, and a `TextView`.

When I run the app and press the btn+ in the first item, I don't know why but the value of the `TextView` in the last item is incremented. When I click the btn-, again the value of the last `TextView` is decremented.

This is my adapter:

```
package com.example.lie_.tablayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.iarcuschin.simpleratingbar.SimpleRatingBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Ali on 17/08/2017.
 */

public class MenuListPizzaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    View vv;
    TextView txtOrderNUM;
    int counter=0;

    private ArrayList <BuyMenuListPizza> BuyMenuListPizza;
    private Context C;

    public MenuListPizzaAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<BuyMenuListPizza> BuyMenuListPizza) {
        this.BuyMenuListPizza = BuyMenuListPizza;
        this.C=c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return BuyMenuListPizza.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return BuyMenuListPizza.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View View, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (View == null) {
            View = LayoutInflater.from(C).inflate(R.layout.buy_menu_list_pizza, parent, false);
        }

        TextView txtitemname = (TextView)View.findViewById(R.id.txtitemname);
        SimpleRatingBar ratingbar = (SimpleRatingBar)View.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
        final TextView txtitemcontent = (TextView)View.findViewById(R.id.txtitemcontent);
        ImageView btnOrderADD = (ImageView)View.findViewById(R.id.btnOrderADD);
        ImageView btnOrderDEL = (ImageView)View.findViewById(R.id.btnOrderDEL);
        ImageView imgitem = (ImageView)View.findViewById(R.id.imgitem);

        txtitemname.setText(BuyMenuListPizza.get(position).getName());
        ratingbar.setRating(BuyMenuListPizza.get(position).getRating());
        txtitemcontent.setText(BuyMenuListPizza.get(position).getContents());
        btnOrderADD.setImageResource(BuyMenuListPizza.get(position).getImgplus());
        btnOrderDEL.setImageResource(BuyMenuListPizza.get(position).getImgminues());
        imgitem.setImageResource(BuyMenuListPizza.get(position).getImgpizza());

        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"Position getView : " + position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        txtOrderNUM = (TextView)View.findViewById(R.id.txtOrderNUM);
        txtOrderNUM.setText(BuyMenuListPizza.get(position).getCount() + "");

        btnOrderADD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int coun= BuyMenuListPizza.get(position).getCount();
                coun++;
                txtOrderNUM.setText( coun+"");
            }
        });

        btnOrderDEL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int coun= BuyMenuListPizza.get(position).getCount();
                coun--;
                if(coun<0){
                }
                else
                    txtOrderNUM.setText(coun+"");
            }
        });

        return View;
    }
}
```

This is my Fragment class :

```
public  class Pizza extends Fragment   {
    TextView txtOrderNUM;

    ArrayList<BuyMenuListPizza> arrayList;
    ListView MenuPizzaList;
    Context c;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pizza, container, false);

        MenuPizzaList = ( ListView)android.findViewById(R.id.MenuPizzaList);
        arrayList=BuyMenuListPizzaCollection.getBuyMenuListPizza();
        MenuPizzaList.setAdapter(new MenuListPizzaAdapter(container.getContext(),arrayList));

 //   MenuPizzaList.setOnItemClickListener(new oncitemlicklistener());

    return android;
}
```

Please don't say go to xml file and change attribute because I changed that and my code is running and `OnClickListener` is ok but it doesn't work correctly.

I have searched for more than several days and I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found problem solving use : notyficationitemselected(getadapterposition)